# Oracle based entity continuously fails with Invalid Cast C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I am currently using Entity framework 4.3 to map a legacy oracle database. All of the data types seem to me to be compatible with the Oracle data types, however it always throws a `TargetInvocationException` with an inner exception of `InvalidCastException`. 
The table in question uses a composite key, I am not sure if this directly relates to the reason i am receiving the exception or not.
 my current code is as follows

**Config Class:**

```
class NoteConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Note>
{
    public NoteConfig()
    {

        Property(m => m.DateChanged).HasColumnName("DATE_CHANGED");
        Property(m => m.ObjectId).HasColumnName("OBJECT_ID");
        Property(m => m.ObjectType).HasColumnName("OBJECT_TYPE");
        Property(m => m.Subject).HasColumnName("SUBJECT");
        Property(m => m.Text).HasColumnName("TEXT");
        Property(m => m.EnteredBy).HasColumnName("ENTERED_BY");
        Property(m => m.LineNo).HasColumnName("LINE_NO");
        Property(m => m.LanguageId).HasColumnName("LANGUAGE_ID");

        //composite key mapping 
        HasKey(m =>
            new { 
                    m.ObjectType,
                    m.ObjectId, 
                    m.LanguageId,
                    m.Subject, 
                    m.LineNo,

            });


        ToTable("TSW_INT_NOTES", Settings.Default.DbSchema);
    }
}
```

**Model Class:**

```
public class Note
{

  //  comp key (languageid, objectid, lineno, object type, subject
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateChanged { get; set; }
    public string  EnteredBy { get; set; }
    public string LineNo { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }


}
```

**Table Layout:**

[image: Table Layout]

**Breakpoint Output:**

[image: Breakpoint Output]

Comment: I believe that it is likely the `DATE_CHANGED` causing the issue. [Save C# DateTime to Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218326/how-can-save-datetime-c-sharp-language-to-oracle10g-database), [Problem with Inserting C# Date to Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698339/problem-with-inserting-date-oracle-and-c-sharp), and [C# connecting to Oracle Datetime formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534250/c-sharp-connecting-to-oracle-db-datetime-formatting).

Comment: [EF maps Oracle's `NUMBER` to decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10149610/861716), so `LanguageId` can also cause problems.

Comment: strange thing with the those theories is that my other entities work fine with those types and i also tried mapping them directly to string types with the same result

Comment: also note josh this is using Entity Framework with oracles EF4 Access Components and is usually automatically handled by their EF datasourcing and not using plain string sql that those posts refer to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Was a number datatype issue but it was on the lineno field and appears that ef throws an exception if you try to map a number datatype when the decimal places is set < 0
and will not automatically truncate decimal values when defining as int in c# as it would with a float or double value in c#

Comment: oops i usually am pretty good at remembering to do that must have forgot on this one